# isnull in SSRS expressions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

How to use this formula in ssrs-expression

```
=NOT(isnull({Command.AAID})) or NOT(isnull({Command.HDomain}))
or NOT(isnull({Command.Adomain}))
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried isnothing()?

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're trying to do is display data based on whether or not a field has data in it or not? You can always use an IIF statement with ISNOTHING. See below for the expression.

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Field!Whatever),0,Field!Whatever)
```

If that doesn't answer your question, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So to convert `Crystal formula` to `SSRS-Expression`,

You need to write expression like below,

```
=IIF(Not(IsNothing(Field!AAID)) OR Not(IsNothing(Field!HDomain)) OR NOt(IsNothing(Field!Adomain)),"TruePart","FalsePart")
```

This expression will work for you!