# Defined expression in SSRS report is displaying #ERROR

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression

I have defined an expression in one of my cells from my `dataset1`. My Design window and I have to repeat for each month's cells but I'm getting an #ERROR when I click on the `PREVIEW` tab in SSRS.

My thought is if the `ActivityMonth value = 1` and the `Type value = "PIF"` then display the value in the Data column.

```
=IIF(Fields!Activity_Month.Value = 1 AND Fields!Type.Value = "PIF", Fields!Data.Value, 0)
```

I got this WARNING from SSRS:

> [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox1471.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

But it ran successfully.

Comment: he logical `And` operator ist written `And`. The `&` operator is the one for concatenating strings, so `Fields!Activity_Month.Value = 1 & Fields!Type.Value = "PIF"` will most likely result in something like `"TrueFalse"` which cannot be evaluated as a boolean expression.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'll try that.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: When I changed the & to "AND" then I got this WARNING from SSRS:  

[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox1471.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.  But it ran successfully.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments and the edit history, it looks like you have used `&` mark which is used to concatenate strings instead of `AND` keyword. After editing the expression - for me - the following expression looks great:

```
 =IIF(Fields!Activity_Month.Value = 1 AND Fields!Type.Value = "PIF", Fields!Data.Value, 0)
```

But i have two remarks:

It may cause an error due to the different data types returned by the expression (`0` is integer, `Data.Value` has another data type:

If `Fields!Data.Value` is of type string then use the following expression:

```
 =IIF(Fields!Activity_Month.Value = 1 AND Fields!Type.Value = "PIF", Fields!Data.Value, "0")
```

Another thing to mention is that if value contains null it may throw an exception, so you have to check if field contains null:

- [SSRS expression replace NULL with another field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234993/ssrs-expression-replace-null-with-another-field-value)
- [isnull in SSRS expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762842/isnull-in-ssrs-expressions)

Comment: @Melinda if it solved the issue. why not accepting it